# unable to create-react-app using npx install command

Tags: javascript

i am unable to install npx-react-app as it is getting stopped at the below point

```
Acer@LAPTOP-OTBULEBK MINGW64 ~/Desktop/coding (dev)   
$ npx create-react-app hello

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\coding\hello.           

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
```

if it is processing from the above stoppable step it is showing error as below

```
$ npx create-react-app hello

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\coding\hello.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\coding\hello\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\coding\hello\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\coding\hello\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

+ react-scripts@3.4.1
+ react-dom@16.13.1
+ cra-template@1.0.3
+ react@16.13.1
added 1602 packages from 751 contributors and audited 1606 packages in 309.352s

60 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 4981 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

I have the below node/npm versions installed

```
Acer@LAPTOP-OTBULEBK MINGW64 ~/Desktop/coding (dev) $ node -v
v12.16.2
Acer@LAPTOP-OTBULEBK MINGW64 ~/Desktop/coding (dev) $ npm -v
6.14.4
Acer@LAPTOP-OTBULEBK MINGW64 ~/Desktop/coding (dev) $ npx -v
6.14.4
```

after facing  with this issue i uninstalled above installation and install the current version

```
Acer@LAPTOP-OTBULEBK MINGW64 ~/Desktop/coding (dev) $node -v
v14.5.0
Acer@LAPTOP-OTBULEBK MINGW64 ~/Desktop/coding (dev) $ npm -v
6.14.5
```

but still it is showing error as above

Comment: Are those errors or warnings? Is your project actually being created and are you able to run it?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because some packages now actually make it quite a subtle demand to fund their projects before using it.

`npm` has added a new command `npm fund <YOUR PACKAGE NAME>` which will list down all the websites that are sort of requiring funding.

You can skip funding any of them (Not so nice but neither is open force forcing funding) by using:

`npm install --no-fund <YOUR PACKAGE NAME>`

You might want to consider reading this: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc and this https://dev.to/ruyadorno/npm-6-13-0-7f3 for clarity.

Let me know if this helps and if not, I will figure this out together with you.

Comment: Thanks for your response mw509 i have tried the command you have posted but it's not working.

Comment: Which one did you try?

Comment: i have tried npm install --no-fund <YOUR PACKAGE NAME>

Comment: You replace the <YOUR PACKAGE NAME> with your package name. Eg: npm install -no-fund  reactpackage. And read the links too